# Tab closes when opening nested tab

Tags: html, jquery, css

Below example has a tab called London with another tab in it called Paris. How can I open Paris without the London tab closing?

The example is directly from W3SCHOOL but modified a bit to fit my use case.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
</div>


<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  </div>
  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent" >
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
  </div>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

I believe the issue is that the "active" class disappears from London and therefore closes as soon as I press Paris. But I am not good with jQuery.

I guess it can easily be tested on the W3 interface:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs

Comment: Thanks for the Run Code Snippet edit

Comment: Your answer is working just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter your `.tabcontent` element collection based on whether they share the same parent element with your target tab.

I've also slightly refactored some other parts of the code, please compare, the changes are self-explanatory.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  let i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  const targetTab = document.querySelector(`#${cityName}.tabcontent`);
  tabcontent = [...document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent")].filter(el => el.parentElement === targetTab.parentElement);
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].hidden = true;
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  targetTab.style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
</div>


<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  </div>
  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using classList.
It is possible to clear all displays with optional button.

```js
// filterSelection("all");  // optional initial display

function filterSelection(c) {
  sel = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  for (let el of sel) { 
    el.classList.remove('show');
    if (el.classList.contains(c) || c == 'all') el.classList.add('show');
  } 
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('#btnContainer .btn');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    for (let j=0; j<btns.length; j++) { btns[j].classList.remove('active'); }
    evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

```css
 .filterDiv {
   background-color: #2196F3;
   color: #ffffff;
   margin: 2px;
   display: none;

   padding: 6px 12px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-top: none;
 }
 .show { display: block; }
 .container {
   margin-top: 2px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
/* Style the buttons */
 .btn {
   font-size: larger;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .btn:hover { background-color: #ddd; }
 .btn.active {
   background-color: #666;
   color: white;
 }
```

```html
<h2>City Countries</h2>

<div id="btnContainer">
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('London')"> London </button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Paris')"> Paris </button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Tokyo')"> Tokyo </button>

  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
<!--      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('')"> Show none</button> <!-- optional -->
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div id="London" class="filterDiv London">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="Paris" class="filterDiv Paris">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
 </div>
 <div id="Tokyo" class="filterDiv Tokyo">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```